# Python Key Error While Extracting From XML File

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to extract data from XML files and I can able to extract data from single file only or one by one but I want to extract them all instead of calling file name one by one and There are near 100 files inside the folder and files name started with numbers. Like 1.xml, 2.xml etc. Here is my XML file and python code. Please have a look. I'm a facing a **KeyError: 'Value'**

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xsi:schemaLocation="CDA.xsd">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <languageCode code="en-US"/>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <addr use="HP">
        <streetAddressLine>3345 Elm Street</streetAddressLine>
        <city>Aurora</city>
        <state>CO</state>
        <postalCode>80011</postalCode>
        <country>US</country>
      </addr>
      <telecom value="tel:+1(303)-554-8889" use="HP"/>
      <patient>
        <name use="L">
          <given>Janson</given>
          <given>J</given>
          <family>Example</family>
        </name>
      </patient>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Python Code

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\files'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
        continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for leads in tree.findall('.//{urn:hl7-org:v3}patientRole'):
        number = leads.find('{urn:hl7-org:v3}telecom').attrib['value']
        print(number)
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong XPath to find all the `patientRole/telecom` elements, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

txt = """<ClinicalDocument> xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xsi:schemaLocation="CDA.xsd">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <languageCode code="en-US"/>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <addr use="HP">
        <streetAddressLine>3345 Elm Street</streetAddressLine>
        <city>Aurora</city>
        <state>CO</state>
        <postalCode>80011</postalCode>
        <country>US</country>
      </addr>
      <telecom value="tel:+1(303)-554-8889" use="HP"/>
      <patient>
        <name use="L">
          <given>Janson</given>
          <given>J</given>
          <family>Example</family>
        </name>
      </patient>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(txt)

for leads in tree.findall('.//*patientRole/telecom'):
    print(leads.attrib["value"])
# tel:+1(303)-554-8889
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Be Chiller Too but You didn't read my details. I've near 100 files. So I can't call Et.fromstring(txt)

Comment: Yes, I created a minimal working example. You can parse your files on your filesystem using `ET.parse()`. The problem in your code was in the `findall` part.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)